# Azure timer function. When to add cursor.close

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am very new to Azure functions and have a question.  I am working on an Azure timer function that pulls data via an API and inserts it into an Azure SQL db.  I am able to do all that part successfully.  However, at the end of the script, I get the following error:

Exception: ProgrammingError: Attempt to use a closed cursor.

My question is, when would I include cursor.close?  Should I have that in there at all?  I assume yes, but, if so, where do I use that?

If I comment it out, it works fine, but I feel like I should have that in there.

Here's my code:

```
def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    gp_data=get_properties()
    for index, row in gp_data.iterrows():
                cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO dbo.get_properties3 (propertyid, property_name, street_address, 
            city, state_code, zip_code, phone, email, manager, currentperiod_start, 
                currentperiod_end, as_of_date) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""", \
                row.propertyid, row.property_name, row.street_address, row.city, row.state_code, row.zip_code, \
                    row.phone, row.email, row.manager, \
                     row.currentperiod_start, row.currentperiod_end,row.as_of_date)
    cnxn.commit()
    # cursor.close()
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, I think the line of code `cursor.close()` is unnecessary because it can be garbage collected like any other object in python. Each running instance of your timer function will not be affected even though you don't add `cursor.close()`.

Comment: Thank you!  I had a feeling that was the answer, but I wasn't sure if the closing of the cursor was going to happen implicitly or if it needed to be called explicitly.